# Is there any exposed api for setting jitter buffer for video in webrtc with JavaScript？

Tags: video, webrtc, jitter

Is there any exposed api for setting jitter buffer in webrtc with JavaScript？
I have read some documents，but can only found api to set audio jitter buffer in

```
new RTCPeerConnection({
    rtcAudioJitterBufferMaxPackets: 75,
    rtcAudioJitterBufferFastAccelerate: true
})
```

I want to know if there is similar api for video to set jitter buffer.

Comment: Even the audio part doesn't work. It was an origin trial (i.e. you could contact Google to ask them to enable it for your web domain) years ago, but it was eventually abandoned: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=904764